# turning a matrix of chars into a matrix of numbers

Tags: matlab

I have to generate a 4 by 7 random matrix from the concatenation of a 7 digit number, and then do some manipulations with the resulting matrix. However, the matrix is composed of chars. How would I convert it to numbers so that it remains unchanged (i.e binary). Currently the code I have is:

```
t = dec2bin(12426171242617,28);
Gran = [t(1:7);t(8:14);t(15:21);t(22:28)]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

`Gran2 = (Gran == '1');`

This gives a matrix of logicals. If you want a matrix of doubles:

`Gran3 = 1*Gran2;`